# Check 10000K+ URL

Tags: python, linux, bash, curl

Well i want to check 100000k+ url in linux.

About those links those are actually OTA[zip] of my android.

Among those links there is only one valid link rest give 404 error.

So how to check all links in less time period in linux server or web server[apache].

**structure of urls:**

> http://link.com/updateOTA_1.zip
>
> http://link.com/updateOTA_2.zip
>
> http://link.com/updateOTA_999999999.zip

**Okay what i tried**

i made this script but it is really slow. http://pastebin.com/KVxnzttA I also increase thread upto 500 then my server crashed :[

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in {1487054155500..1487055000000}
do
  if [ $((a%50)) = 0 ]
    then
    curl -s -I http://link.com/updateOTA_$((a)).zip | head -n1 & 
    curl -s -I http://link.com/updateOTA_$((a+1)).zip | head -n1 &
    curl -s -I http://link.com/updateOTA_$((a+2)).zip | head -n1 &
    curl -s -I http://link.com/updateOTA_$((a+3)).zip | head -n1 &
    curl -s -I http://link.com/updateOTA_$((a+4)).zip | head -n1 &
...
    curl -s -I http://link.com/updateOTA_$((a+49)).zip | head -n1 &
    curl -s -I http://link.com/updateOTA_$((a+50)).zip | head -n1
    wait
    echo "$((a))"
  fi
done
```

i tried with aria2, but highest thread on aria2 is 16, so again failed.

tried with some online tools, but they give me 100url restrictions.

Comment: why people giving minus rate.....

Comment: @TomUdding i tried aria2c

Comment: Because Stack Overflow is a site where we help people with their code and/or give our opinion. We are not people who just write some code for someone who hasn't tried to do it themselves.

Comment: People are downvoting your question because you've not shown what you've tried so far. It's best to not approach SO as a code-writing service, but instead ask a specific question about specific code.

Comment: @TomUdding i made this script but it is really slow. http://pastebin.com/KVxnzttA I also increase thread upto 500 then my server crashed :[

Comment: You should probably do fewer URLs at the same time. And it all comes down to your connection.

Comment: @TomUdding right now that script scanning 1035 url per minute, but thats not enough. thats why im finding shortcut. is that possible to increase thread in aria2c?

Comment: You could try to increase `--max-concurrent-downloads` in aria2c but I don't think that will help.

Comment: @TomUdding okay i tried but that its not helpful..... scanning 800 urls per minute.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnu-parallel/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However i found solution using aria2c

now it scanning 7k url per minute.

thanks to all

`aria2c -i url -s16 -x16 --max-concurrent-downloads=1000`

Answer (score 1):

Running `curl` 100,000+ times is going to be slow. Instead, write batches of URLs to a single instance of `curl` to reduce the overhead of starting `curl`.

```
# This loop doesn't require pre-generating a list of a million integers
for ((a=1487054155500; a<=1487055000000; a+=50)); do
  for(k=0; k<50; k++)); do
    printf 'url = %s\n' "http://link.com/updateOTA_$((a+k)).zip"
  done | curl -I -K - -w 'result: %{http_code} %{url_effective}' | grep -F 'result:' > batch-$a.txt
done
```

The `-w` option is used to produce output associating each URL with its result, should you want that.

Comment: thanks. Getting 2 error >> Warning: error trying read config from the '-w' file
>>curl: (6) Could not resolve host: result

Comment: Ah, small typo; I forgot the `-` argument for `-K` to tell it which config file (standard input) to use.

Comment: `curl: unknown --write-out variable: 'http_status'` still getting error